# Real vs. complex series coefficients

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, series-expansion

I hope that this question is not a duplicate but I was unable to find it here (or somewhere else in the internet). For some reason, mathematica makes some expressions unnecessarily complicated. Consider for instance

```
ClearAll[c];
c[n_, b_] = 
FullSimplify[SeriesCoefficient[1/((x - 1)^2 + b^2)^2, {x, 0, n}], {n >= 0, b > 0}]
```

This yields

```
(((1 + I b)^-n (-I + b (2 + n)))/(-I + b)^2 + ((1 - I b)^-n (I + b (2 + n)))/(I + b)^2)/(4 b^3)
```

i.e. a complex expression. Clearly, the series coefficients are real if `b` is. Attempts to convince mathematica to account for this are not really successful:

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[c[n, b]]]
(*(1/(2 b^3))(1 + b^2)^(-2 - n/2) E^(-(1/2)
I n (Arg[1 - I b] + 
Arg[1 + I b])) (b (-n + b^2 (2 + n)) Cos[
 1/2 n (Arg[1 - I b] - Arg[1 + I b])] - (1 + b^2 (3 + 2 n)) Sin[
 1/2 n (Arg[1 - I b] - Arg[1 + I b])])*)
```

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to obtain reasonable expressions that are manifestly real.

Comment: Try this: `Assuming[n ∈ Integers && n >= 0, FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[SeriesCoefficient[1/((x - 1)^2 + b^2)^2, {x, 0, n}], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]]]`

Comment: @J.M. WOW, thanks! Works perfectly! Now I learned a new trick. Still wondering why mathematica doesn't do this by default.